# Find a word in a string that has no spaces in it PHP

Tags: php, xml, string, parsing, find

I parse an XML file with PHP. My problem is I have a dynamic string with multiple lines and each line has no space char on it, and I want to find a word on that string. String's length is dynamic so it changes every time.

Since strings length is dynamic I can't use something like `$c = substr($string, 0, -1)` or I can't use something like `$i=stripos($story," word");` because there is no space in the string.

example string is 4 lines and  I want to detect the word ARC.docx on second line before `</a>`:

```
<![CDATA[
In <a href='/home/Apps/ARCMeeting'>ARCMeeting</a>, You edited the file <a href='https://dropbox.com/get/Apps/ARCMeeting/ARC.docx?w=d3' title='&#47;Apps&#47;ARCMeeting&#47;ARC.docx'>ARC.docx</a>.
<br/>
]]>
```

My goal is add that ARC.docx on second line before `</a>` to a message body

```
$message='X File has been edited!';
```

so I can print

```
$message='ARC.docx File has been edited!';
```

How can I detect word that in between `.......>exampleword</a>.` in above string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is html, use XML Parser and Xpath to query the content of your `<a>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

In your case it will look something like:

```
$subject = "In <a href='/home/Apps/ARCMeeting'>ARCMeeting</a>, You edited the file <a href='https://dropbox.com/get/Apps/ARCMeeting/ARC.docx?w=d3' title='&#47;Apps&#47;ARCMeeting&#47;ARC.docx'>ARC.docx</a>"

preg_match("/title=(.*)>(.*)<\/a>/U", $subject, $matches);

echo $matches[2]; // $matches[2] will contain `ARC.docx`
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [DOM parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) such as the one built into PHP.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$html_string = <<<EOD
 <![CDATA[
 In <a href='/home/Apps/ARCMeeting'>ARCMeeting</a>, You edited the file <a href='https://dropbox.com/get/Apps/ARCMeeting/ARC.docx?w=d3' title='&#47;Apps&#47;ARCMeeting&#47;ARC.docx'>ARC.docx</a>.
 <br/>
 ]]>
EOD;

@$doc->loadHTML($html_string);

$urls = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($urls as $url) {
 echo $url->nodeValue;
}
```

> ARC.docx

Comment: your answer gives me string also in first `a` there are two `a` tags and out put is `In ARCMeeting, You edited the file ARC.docx` I have to parse that againg to find the last word